# MySQL user permissions issue

Tags: mysql, database, security, permissions

I'm facing a problem with user access control. To be more clear, the mysql user I create has access to other tables than what I've given access to. 
Let's say I log in as root into mysql and there are many databases, and in database "test", there are many tables one of which is "news". 
I want to create user specifically having access only to "select" values from "test.news". This is how it looked:

```sql
mysql> grant select on test.news to 'new_user2'@'localhost' identified by 'XXXXXXX';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Flushed privileges: `flush privileges;`

Now, log out, and  I login as new_user2:

```sql
/opt/lampp/bin/./mysql -u new_user2 -p
```

and want to see databases there:

```sql
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This was good, in the sense, there were other databases in the "root" account which were not visible to new_user2. Then, I wanted to see tables in test. So-

```sql
use test;
show tables;
```

This is the first shock for me.. 
 I saw all the tables in the "test" database, which I was not expecting. All I wanted to see was "news" table. Or is it normal that all users who have been given access to one table in a database, can actually view all the tables?

second shock, I used `select *` for another table- "user", which is essentially another table in "test", and I could see all the contents in user table.

So, when I created "new_user2" and granted permission only to access test.news, how can it access test.user? `select * from news` is working fine..

Did I really restrict access to all other tables in "test" database? If not, how do I do it?

OK. As if this is not sufficient, I can actually delete tables created by 'root'..

```sql
mysql> drop table member;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.42 sec)
```

These are the grants for 'new_user2'@'localhost' when logged in root...

```sql
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'new_user2'@'localhost';
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for new_user2@localhost                                                                                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'new_user2'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' |
| GRANT SELECT ON `test`.`news` TO 'new_user2'@'localhost'                                                         |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I feel, I'm missing something basic here. Please help me this. Thank you so much.

Comment: I've added the output for - SHOW GRANTS FOR 'new_user2'@'localhost' when logged in as root. Please see above in the question- the bold part.